# Why does my Vuforia 8.0 AR app work with a PC webcam, but not with a phone camera, and how do I fix it?

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am making an AR recognition app, the first time I have done so in 2018.3. I have installed the database and target info from the Vuforia developer portal. I have imported my model, and created an animator controller. I have an app key in place from Vuforia.

In Game mode using an attached webcam, the detection looks and works great, and the state manager correctly begins the animation. Cool.

[image]

Building for Android 7 proceeds without problem or console error. The app launches, but after target recco, only a small flickering portion of the model appears over the target... in fact, I **assume** it is the model, but it looks weird and meshy, as though it is cut off with straight edges.

Changing distance and angle with the phone camera does not change. Changing the scale of the object in Unity and recompiling does not change.

The behavior I am seeing does not occur if I replace my model with default cube. I also recalculated normals, and lowered the poly count: still no luck.

All input welcome.

Comment: This question would be clearer if it included an image or video of the symptoms of the problem, "a small flickering portion of the model appears over the target...weird and meshy, as though it is cut off with straight edges"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer: Too many polys. The model was higher poly count that the phone could drive.